# Replace n occurances of strings in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In contrast to `string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])` the `pandas.DataFrame.replace()` function seems to lack an argument that limits the number of occurrences you wish to replace.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['horse', 'dog', 'snake', 'dog'], 'col2': ['dog', 'snake', 'dog', 'cow']})

$ python run.py
    col1   col2
0  horse    dog
1    dog  snake
2  snake    dog
3    dog    cow
```

I would like to replace **n** = 3 occurances of **dog** in df by BEAR (across all columns and rows).

Desired output:

```
$ python run.py
    col1   col2
0  horse    BEAR
1    BEAR  snake
2  snake    dog
3    BEAR    cow
```

What's the best way to achieve this? I would like to avoid iterating through every cell of the df.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is unstack and mask then unstack:

```
n = 3
s = df.unstack()
c = s.eq("dog").groupby(s).cumsum()
s.mask(c<=n,s.replace("dog","BEAR")).unstack(0)
```

Another alternative using numpy:

```
arr = np.cumsum(np.ravel(df.eq("dog").to_numpy(),'F')).reshape(df.shape,order='F')
df[:] = np.where(arr<=3,df.replace("dog","BEAR"),df) #changes the array inplace
print(df)
```

---

```
    col1   col2
0  horse   BEAR
1   BEAR  snake
2  snake    dog
3   BEAR    cow
```

Comment: thanks, this works! Any idea how to optimize it for performance?

Comment: @ComfortEagle this was the first thought that came to me, however i will try to see if I find another more optimal way

Comment: @ComfortEagle added anoter alternative , can you test that as well

Comment: for a new dataframe use `pd.DataFrame(np.where(arr<=3,df.replace("dog","BEAR"),df),columns=df.columns)` instead of the last line

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks a lot, I would upvote 10x if I could ;)

Comment: @ComfortEagle Glad that helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `DataFrame.mask` and `DataFrame.fillna` with argument `limit=3` which only replaces the first 3 `NaN`:

```
df.mask(df.eq('dog')).unstack().fillna('BEAR', limit=3).fillna('dog').unstack(level=0)

    col1   col2
0  horse   BEAR
1   BEAR  snake
2  snake    dog
3   BEAR    cow
```

---

Or more generic in a function with arguments:

```
def replace_n(data, to_replace, new, n):
    data = data.mask(data.eq(to_replace))
    data = data.unstack().fillna(new, limit=n)
    data = data.fillna(to_replace).unstack(level=0)
    
    return data


replace_n(df, 'dog', 'BEAR', n=3)

    col1   col2
0  horse   BEAR
1   BEAR  snake
2  snake    dog
3   BEAR    cow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this loop:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['horse', 'dog', 'snake', 'dog'], 'col2': ['dog', 'snake', 'dog', 'cow']}

n = 3

for k in d.keys():
    for i,s in enumerate(d[k]):
        if s == 'dog' and n > 0:
            d[k].pop(i)
            d[k].insert(i,'BEAR')
            n -= 1

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    col1   col2
0  horse   BEAR
1   BEAR  snake
2  snake    dog
3   BEAR    cow
```